# Obtener documentos PDF de las subcarpetas con Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los documentos PDF que se encuentran en diferentes subcarpetas.
La estructura de las carpetas es de la siguiente forma:

1. **Carpeta principal:** *test*
2. **Subcarpetas:** Una por cada asignatura
3. **Sub-subcarpetas:** Cada carpeta corresponde a cada una de las sesiones de cada asignatura. El nombre de cada una de ellas es `'Session XYZ'`

El código que planteo es el siguiente:

```
import os
import shutil

folder = r"\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test"
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir()]

for sub in subfolders:
    for f in os.listdir(sub):
        src = os.path.join(sub, f)
        dst = os.path.join(folder, f)
        shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Estoy ejecutándolo desde Jupyter Notebook. El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-04055aad47a2> in <module>
      9         src = os.path.join(sub, f)
     10         dst = os.path.join(folder, f)
---> 11         shutil.move(src, dst)

~\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    784         real_dst = os.path.join(dst, _basename(src))
    785         if os.path.exists(real_dst):
--> 786             raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
    787     try:
    788         os.rename(src, real_dst)

Error: Destination path '\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\Session 1\Session 1' already exists
```

El problema es que extrae las carpetas `'Session XYZ'` sobre la carpeta `'test'`, y no extrae los documentos que están contenidos en cada una de las subcarpetas `'Session XYZ'`.
Adicionalmente, cada una de las asignaturas tiene el mismo nombre de carpetas y entonces el error salta porque ya existe una carpeta con el nombre 'Session XYZ'.

Lo que me gustaría obtener es una carpeta con todos los documentos *PDF* contenidos en todas las carpetas que comentaba.
Lamentablemente no controlo mucho Python ni la forma de hacer estos cambios ya que estoy comenzando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python tiene un módulo subestimado, [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), el cual busca busca patrones en el sistema de archivos. Una ventaja es que, por un argumento, puede habilitar recursividad en el directorio de búsqueda.

```py
import os, glob, shutil

folder_src = r"C:\Users\Carpeta\origen" # <-- Hay subdirectorios
folder_dst = r"C:\Carpeta\destino"

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder_src, '**/*.pdf'), recursive=True)

for src in files:
    fname = os.path.basename(src) # Nombre del archivo
    dst = os.path.join(folder_dst, fname)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

### ¡Buen día!

Para el manejo de rutas lo correcto es usar el módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name). Es más intuitivo en términos de sintaxis, más fácil de usar y tiene más funciones con respecto al módulo *os* tal como lo aclara este post de medium [Don’t Use Python OS Library Any More When Pathlib Can Do](https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-python-os-library-any-more-when-pathlib-can-do-141fefb6bdb5) donde el autor hace hincapié en porque debe usarse *pathlib* y no *os* para el manejo del sistema.

En tu código podemos notar que se importan 3 módulos *`os, glob, shutill`* a continuación notaras que solo importaré dos módulos `pathlib y shutill` optimizando recursos y haciendo del script un poco más legible. recuerda:

> **La legibilidad es importante.** [Zen de python](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_de_Python)

### Código:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

ruta = Path.cwd()
full_list = [ shutil.copy(str(archivo.as_posix()), f"arch/{archivo.name}") for archivo in Path(ruta).glob('**/*.pdf')]

print(full_list)
```

### Explicación:

Importamos la librerías que vamos a utilizar, en este caso `pathlib y shutil` paso seguido procedemos a extraer la ruta relativa en la que nos encontramos con `Path.cwd()` de no estar trabajando con la `relativa`, asignamos a la variable ruta la `ruta absoluta` ([Rutas relativas y absolutas](https://denovatoanovato.net/rutas-relativas-y-rutas-absolutas/)) y es en la siguiente línea de código donde viene lo interesante. A través de una [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) iremos itereando las carpetas que se encuentran en la ruta y extrayendo las rutas de los archivos que sean de tipo *`pdf`* eso lo hacemos con:

```
for archivo in Path(ruta).glob('**/*.pdf')
```

Paso seguido creé una carpeta manualmente llamada **arch** y es allí donde almacenaré las copias de los pdf, esto lo hacemos con shutil el cual recibe dos parámetros:

**1.** La ruta del archivo que se copiará (la cual la extrajimos anteriormente)

**2.** La nueva ruta donde se copiara el archivo + el nombre del archivo en este caso quise llamarlo igual.

Finalmente, si imprimimos la lista nos devolverá la ruta donde se copiaron los archivos pdf